# Lua: module 'castl.runtime' not found

Tags: lua, dependencies, castl

I am new to Lua. I compiled a JS file to lua 5.2 using [castl](https://github.com/PaulBernier/castl):

```
castl -o script.js
```

This created a file named **script.js.lua**. This is the first line of my new lua file:

```
local _ENV = require("castl.runtime");
```

I tried running that file with `lua52 script.js.lua`, but I got this error:

```
C:\Program Files\lua-5.2.4_Win64_bin\lua52.exe: script.js.lua:1: module 'castl.runtime' not found:
        no field package.preload['castl.runtime']
        no file 'C:\Program Files\lua-5.2.4_Win64_bin\lua\castl\runtime.lua'
        no file 'C:\Program Files\lua-5.2.4_Win64_bin\lua\castl\runtime\init.lua'
        no file 'C:\Program Files\lua-5.2.4_Win64_bin\castl\runtime.lua'
        no file 'C:\Program Files\lua-5.2.4_Win64_bin\castl\runtime\init.lua'
        no file '.\castl\runtime.lua'
        no file 'C:\Program Files\lua-5.2.4_Win64_bin\castl\runtime.dll'
        no file 'C:\Program Files\lua-5.2.4_Win64_bin\loadall.dll'
        no file '.\castl\runtime.dll'
        no file 'C:\Program Files\lua-5.2.4_Win64_bin\castl\runtime52.dll'
        no file '.\castl\runtime52.dll'
        no file 'C:\Program Files\lua-5.2.4_Win64_bin\castl.dll'
        no file 'C:\Program Files\lua-5.2.4_Win64_bin\loadall.dll'
        no file '.\castl.dll'
        no file 'C:\Program Files\lua-5.2.4_Win64_bin\castl52.dll'
        no file '.\castl52.dll'
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'require'
        script.js.lua:1: in main chunk
        [C]: in ?
```

What am I missing? I am on Windows 10.

Comment: From the docs: a Lua runtime library (located in `lua/castl/`) which allows the execution of the code compiled by `castl.js`. Add the same to your environment's LUA_PATH, and it should work.

Answer (score -1):

To answer your question

> What am I missing?

Your problem is that you use a function `require`, but you don't know what this function does. Therefore, you cannot understand the errors it throws when it fails to do what you're expecting it to do.

So first refer to the Lua manual:
https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-require

There you'll find:

> `require` searches for a Lua loader using the path stored in
>   package.path. If that also fails, it searches for a C loader using the
>   path stored in package.cpath. If that also fails, it tries an
>   all-in-one loader (see package.searchers).

and https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-package.path

> The path used by require to search for a Lua loader.
>
> At start-up, Lua initializes this variable with the value of the
>   environment variable `LUA_PATH_5_3` or the environment variable `LUA_PATH`
>   or with a default path defined in luaconf.h, if those environment
>   variables are not defined. Any `;;` in the value of the environment
>   variable is replaced by the default path.

For additional reading:
https://www.lua.org/pil/8.1.html

Entering "Lua require" into any web search will also result in plenty of solutions to your problem.

As hjpotter92 already stated in his comment, you have to tell your computer where to look for the files you want to require unless they are already located in the default folders.
Add the file's location to your `LUA_PATH` environment variable or add it to the `package.path` string before calling the respective require.

Comment: I probably just didn't understand your instructions correctly, but I tried adding a new user variable in the environment variables dialogue named `LUA_PATH` set to `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\repos\clones\castl\lua\castl`. After this I was getting the same error except the error only listed "no file" entries for `.dll` files (no `.lua` files anymore).

Comment: So, noticing that without that environment variable Lua was searching for a `runtime.lua` file in ``C:\Program Files\ua-5.2.4_Win64_bin\lua\castl\``, I copied the `lua` folder in my castl repo into that location (``C:\Program Files\lua-5.2.4_Win64_bin\``). This seems to have moved me past this error on to another...

Comment: I'm sorry but "Entering "Lua require" into any web search"  is not a good advice for answering question at Stackoverflow - answers here supposed to be self-sufficient to some extent.

Comment: @shabunc my answer is self-sufficient. you obviously didn't read it. I explained in detail what causes his problem and how he can solve it. I even named several references. I even explained how to get that information without being spoon-fed on StackOverflow.

Answer (score -1):

I'll leave an answer here since I believe that answer provided is actually not helping to someone who does not know anything about Lua ecosystem.

In order to `require("castl.runtime")` to be resolved one need to set `LUA_PATH`, in this case, for the sake of simplicity let's assume that `castl` distrib is located at `/Users/me/castl`, then you can:

```
export LUA_PATH="/Users/me/castl/lua/?.lua"
```

Now if you'll run Lua script it will be executed properly.